# Open page in new window when a link button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to open a new window when a link button is clicked.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkpackageinfo" CssClass="linkclass" 
    runat="Server" 
    OnClientClick="lnkpackageinfo_Click()">Compare Packages</asp:LinkButton>
```

I want the target page to be given in the code behind because in the target page i want to use querystring to hide few buttons and links. It is clear

```
protected void lnkpackageinfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  long MerchantID = CommonHelper.GetLoggedInMerchant();
  string querystringpackageinfo = ApplicationData.URL_MERCHANT_COMPANY_PACKAGE + "?MerchantCompanyPayment";
  Response.Redirect(querystringpackageinfo, false);
}
```

This doesnot work for me. Where am i doing wrong? Any someone help me out! thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do something like this?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkpackageinfo" CssClass="linkclass" runat="Server"> Compare Packages</asp:LinkButton>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lnkpackageinfo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:window.open('" + GetURL()+  "'); return false;");

}
```

```
public string GetURL()
{
   long MerchantID = CommonHelper.GetLoggedInMerchant(); 
   string querystringpackageinfo = ApplicationData.URL_MERCHANT_COMPANY_PACKAGE + "?   MerchantCompanyPayment"; 

   return querystringpackageinfo;
}
```

Comment: Amamzing. it took few seconds. I understood what it is! Thank you much buddies!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call a server side function (`lnkpackageinfo_Click`) using client side markup (`OnClientClick`).

`OnClientClick` will try to call the JavaScript function you have named in the value of the attribute, which will not be there as the function is a server side (code behind) function.

You need to write a JavaScript function on the page in order for the client to open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need the `()` for one thing. 
Also, Just use `OnClick=lnkpackageinfo_Click` attribute.
Then in that function set a hidden field value to call some javascript to open a new window.